# Difference between 学習する and 習う?

Tags: usage, verbs

Is there any difference between 学習する and 習う?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a difference. Have you read through our other questions with 学習 and 習う, e.g. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13786/multiple-usages-of-%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92%E3%81%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%82%85%E3%81%86 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/the-verbs-of-learning-%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E7%BF%92%E3%81%86-and-%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B6 ?

Comment: 学習する/学ぶ/勉強する  - active, learn from books.

習う/先生に就いて(tsuite)学習する/先生の下で(motode)学習する - passive, directed under the teacher.

Comment: 私は日本語を学習しています I study/learn Japanese actively with textbooks, the net, or the teacher. 私は日本語を習っています I study/learn Japanese at some school directed by someone.

Comment: 学習科目(kamoku) studying subject. 習い事(naraigoto) hobby, usually piano, soccer, swimming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are similar words with subtle differences.

学習 has a bit more formal sound than 習う, and the difference in their meanings derive from that.

For example, 学習 tends to refer to "at desk" formal studies you do at schools and institutions. Mathmatics, science, English, that sort of things.  In contrast, 習う often refers to lessons and extra-school activities such as karate, piano, cooking, and so on (see Worthy7's answer for sentences.)

The border line is blurry, though.

For example, take Worthy7's sentence "向こうの大学じゃ、習ってなかったし" as an example. This refers to a study in an university. But in this case 習う is used because the form of speech is informal.

Likewise, 学習 can be used even if it doesn't involve studying at formal institutions, when a rigid sounding noun form is needed. For example, 生涯学習センター (life-long learning center) is normally just a community center that has short programs, but you don't want to call it 生涯習い事センター because it lacks dignitiy.